# Keyboard shortcut to switch between horizontally split windows in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I've done numerous searches to find out how to switch between two files that are horizontally split but can't seem to find it. I know that you can switch between vertically split files by using the `Goto Next Splitter` option, but there doesn't seem to exist an option for horizontally split. Has anyone else figured this out? Thanks!

An example of a situation where I can't switch between the top and bottom files:
[image: Horizontally split files]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just tried this out, and `Goto Next Splitter` (<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> on mac) works just fine for me on horizontally split panes

Note: Using CLion 2017.1.2

---

If you have IdeaVim installed, you can use the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> - <kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd> command to switch between Vim split panes. See also [How do I switch between panes in split mode in Vim?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-switch-between-panes-in-split-mode-in-Vim)

Comment: For those with IdeaVim you can also use **Control-W** twice to switch between panes

Answer (score 5):

Use `Ctrl + Tab` or `Ctrl + Shift + Tab` to switch between opened buffers (or "file editors", if you like). If you have only two buffers like on your screenshot, you can just press `Ctrl + Tab` and then by pressing `Enter` the other editor will become focused.

**Important addition**:

The shortcut varies depending on your keymap. To figure out proper key combination, open `File -> Settings -> Keymap` and search for "Switcher" keymap in the search field.

Comment: I've been a power user of the Intellij ecosystem for 3 years, never knew about this. Thanks for sharing!